# Redirect to a page with a $tag in php

Tags: php, redirect

I want to redirect to the $loginUrl, how can i make this redirection ?

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://newpage.photoclub-tey.com.cy/facebooklogin/', $permissions);
echo '<a href="'.filter_var($loginUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL).'"><img src="images/glogin.png" alt=""/></a>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php header("Location: " . $loginUrl); ?>
```